# How to check if a column exists, if it does, return a value from it

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

In psycopg2, if I have a table:

```
+------+-----+-------+  
| name | age | color |  
+------+-----+-------+  
| Bob  |  25 | red   |  
| Bill |  50 | blue  |  
| Jane |  45 | black |  
+------+-----+-------+
```

If I do `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mySchema.this_table LIMIT 1")`
then I check if color exists with:
`colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]`
then search colnames for 'color'

then I think I get the row with:
`myrow = importCursor.fetchone()`

but how do I get the 'color' value of that row?
I tried `color = importCursor.fetchone()['color']`
but that doesn't work.

How do I get the color value of the row returned by that SELECT statement? I don't know how many columns there are in the table, or if the 'color' column will always be column #3 I have to do this for a bunch of columns in this table (check if exists, if does, return column value of row) so an efficient way is best!

Comment: `cursor.execute('select color from myschema.this_table limit 1')`, `color = cursor.fetchall()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Select only some columns

If you select only certain columns, then you do know the column order.

```python
cursor.execute("SELECT name, age, color FROM mySchema.this_table LIMIT 1")
```

Now you know that column 0 is `name`, 1 is `age`, 2 is `color`. So you can choose which one with something like `myrow[1]`.

### Get a map of columns first

You can get a map of the returned columns, and then use that to figure out where to fetch.

```python
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
if 'color' in column_names:
    color = cursor.fetchOne()[column_names.index('color')]
```

This should be relatively efficient, because you only need to calculate the column name list one time after the query, and then you can map the column name to a column number with simple list operations like `index` and `in`, which are much faster than hitting the database again.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the response. this doesn't quite work for me though, since I'm not always positive that the column is present. So first I'm actually doing a `select *`, then using `cursor.description` to search for the column name. Then if I find it, I need to check it's value.

Comment: @Acoustic77 See updated answer. I added a way to get the column name map and then use that to figure out which column to snag (only if the column exists). Hope this is more in line with what you were after...